# trying to concatenate a single value to an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to produce a new_array consisting of `old_array[0] + old_array2.slice(1)`

I cannot see how concat would help me here, unless I create a 3rd temporary array out of `old_array[0]`.

Is that the only way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = [1,2,3];

var b = [4,5,6];
```

Then you have two options depending on the result you want. Either:

```
var c = a.slice(1).concat(b[0]);
```

Or:

```
var c = [b[0]].concat(a.slice(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is [`array.unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift), which adds a value (or values) to the start of the array:

```
var fruits = [ "orange", "banana" ];
fruits.unshift("apple");
// Fruits is now ["apple", "orange", "banana"]
```

If you want to produce a new array, you could do this to the result of a slice:

```
var new_array = old_array2.slice(1);
new_array.unshift(old_array[0]);
```

But, since this code just replaces the first element, you could also write:

```
var new_array = old_array2.slice(0);
new_array[0] = old_array[0]; // I prefer this for readability
```

---

I'm not sure about the `slice(1)` in your question, as I don't think it matches the wording of your question. So, here are two more answers:

- If you want to create a new array which is the same as old_array2, but with the first value from old_array at the start of it, use:

  ```
   var new_array = old_array2.slice(0); // Note the slice(0)
   new_array.unshift(old_array[0]);
  ```
- If you want to create a new array which is the same as old_array2, but with the first value replaced with the first value of old_array, use:

  ```
  var new_array = old_array2.slice(0);
  new_array[0] = old_array[0];
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want a new two-element array from those explicitly defined portions of two source arrays, then just do this:

```
new_array = [old_array[0], old_array2.slice(1).toString()];
```

See: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2YXBM/)

*(Note: Second element fixed from originally posed solution, per comment received.)*

Comment: This will result in a two element array, with the second element being an array, which is not what the poster is asking for.

Comment: Looking at your JS fiddle, the `alert(array.toString())` is misleading, because it doesn't show array boundaries. Look at the result in a javascript console - you'll see it's still a two element array, which is not what the poster wants.

Comment: Thanks, @Timothy Jones. I've updated it. I think the poster just wants a new two-element array of the two strings; the item a [0] in old_array and the sliced item in the second array.

Comment: I don't see that from his question, but I agree that there's not a lot of information in it. I will hold off from downvoting you in case your interpretation is correct- but perhaps you could add a note to the answer that makes it clear that your code produces a two element array?

Comment: Thanks for the non-down-vote :-)  When I read the question I thought, "He's not asking for a single element array from two strings, is he?" so I wasn't super sure myself. I mean, generally when somebody want a new array, it's more than one element, since making one from a string is so easy. Trick questions perhaps? :-)